# Bootstrap Footer Modal Spacing not working in React.js

Tags: css, reactjs, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to add a space between these two buttons, So I used bootstraps modal-footer class and I believe the buttons were supposed to have space in between, but there is no spacing. My code is below:

< div className = "modal-footer">

```
        <Button bsStyle = "primary pull-right" formNoValidate={true} type="submit">Submit</Button>

        <Button bsStyle = "default pull-right" onClick={this.resetForm} type="reset">Reset</Button>

        </div>
```

Comment: You might need to add `{' '}` between your components, since the spaces between them will be skipped once the JSX is compiled. For example `<Button />{' '}<Button />`

Comment: @AnthonyGarcia thanks, I tried to implement that, but i am getting two white boxes... Would you mind updating the code above ?

Answer (score 0):

The white-spaces between your JSX tags are not kept once the JSX is compiled to javascript. If you want to keep them anyway, you can do this:

```
<Button bsStyle = "primary pull-right" formNoValidate={true} type="submit">Submit</Button>
{' '}
<Button bsStyle = "default pull-right" onClick={this.resetForm} type="reset">Reset</Button>
```

Comment: Nothing happens when I implement this

Answer (score 0):

Put them inside 'btn-toolbar', not 'modal-footer'. The .modal-footer class is used to define the style for the footer of the modal. For .btn-toolbar class see more info on Bootstrap [documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#btn-groups).

Try this code:

```
        <div className="btn-toolbar">

            <button className="btn btn-primary pull-right" formNoValidate={true} type="submit">Submit</button>

            <button className ="btn btn-primary pull-right" onClick={this.resetForm} type="reset">Reset</button>

        </div>
```

Please note: I have used 'button' html tag **NOT** 'Button' of bootstrap. That's why I have changed the bsstyle to className. You can try on your bootstrap setup.

There are other css methods also using which you can provide space between buttons easiest one is to assign 'margin-right' to button.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I removed the tag pull-right in both and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this I removed the "pull-right" and the spacing worked from bootstraps "modal-footer" class.

```
    <div className= "modal-footer">

    <Button bsStyle = "primary" formNoValidate={true} type="submit">Submit</Button>

    <Button bsStyle = "default" onClick={this.resetForm} type="reset">Reset</Button>

    </div>
```